# Combine three (complex) queries

Tags: mysql

I have one query that I am using to sum stock totals and show the last date updated for each stock item. I have two different stock types 0 and 1 (Incoming, Outgoing). I want to be able to put at the bottom of the page "Last received stock was at:" & "Last shipment was at:".

Heres what I have for my main query to group and sum the inventory:

```
 $query = "Select * 
          FROM (SELECT id, type, color, product, 
                      SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, MAX(Date) AS LatestDate 
                FROM inventory 
                GROUP BY id, color, type) AS alias 
          WHERE TotalQuantity > 0";
```

Now I want to be able to also run these two queries to grab the last updated time for 'stock' 0 and 1 (Incoming, Outgoing)

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(Date) FROM inventory WHERE stock = 0";

$query = "SELECT MAX(Date) FROM inventory WHERE stock = 1";
```

Any help combining these THREE queries? I was trying UNION but not having much luck.

Comment: Sorry what's complex about `SELECT MAX(Date) FROM inventory WHERE stock = 0` ?

Comment: @Seph the first ones complicated ;) if it was three SELECT MAX(Date) I could probably figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this:

```
SELECT  alias.*,
    zeroStock.zeroDate,
    nonzeroStock.nonzeroDate
FROM
    (
        SELECT  id, 
            type, 
            color, 
            product, 
            SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, 
            MAX(Date) AS LatestDate 
        FROM    inventory 
        GROUP BY id, color, type
    ) alias INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, MAX(Date) zeroDate
        FROM inventory 
        WHERE stock = 0
        GROUP BY id
    ) zeroStock on alias.id = zeroStock.id
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, MAX(Date) nonzeroDate
        FROM inventory 
        WHERE stock = 1
        GROUP BY id
    ) nonzeroStock on alias.id = nonzeroStock.id
WHERE alias.TotalQuantity > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
Select
  alias.id,
  alias.type,
  alias.color,
  alias.product,
  Stock0.S0,
  Stock1.S1
FROM (SELECT
        id,
        type,
        color,
        product,
        SUM(Quantity)  AS TotalQuantity,
        MAX(Date)      AS LatestDate
      FROM inventory
      GROUP BY id, color, type) AS alias
  left join (SELECT
               id,
               MAX(Date)         S0
             FROM inventory
             WHERE stock = 0) as Stock0
    on Stock0.id = alias.id
  left join (SELECT
               id,
               MAX(Date)         S1
             FROM inventory
             WHERE stock = 0) as Stock1
    on Stock1.id = alias.id
WHERE TotalQuantity > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to add the dates to each row of your regular select statement.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          SELECT  *
          FROM    (
                    SELECT id, type, color, product, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, MAX(Date) AS LatestDate 
                    FROM inventory 
                    GROUP BY 
                          id, color, type
                  ) AS alias 
          WHERE TotalQuantity > 0
        ) AS q
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(Date) AS MaxIncoming FROM Inventory WHERE stock = 0) AS r
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(Date) AS MaxOutgoing FROM Inventory WHERE stock = 1) AS s
```

[Mysql Cross Join](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqljoin/mysql-cross-join.shtml)

> Cross Join is also called Cartesian Product Join. The Cross Join in
>   SQL return you a result table in which each row from the first table
>   is combined with each rows from the second table

**Edit**

for the record, you can simplify the statement  by using a `HAVING`clause instead of the `WHERE`clause on your TotalQuantity.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          SELECT  id, type, color, product, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, MAX(Date) AS LatestDate 
          FROM    inventory 
          GROUP BY 
                  id, color, type
          HAVING
                  SUM(Quantity) > 0        
        ) AS q
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(Date) AS MaxIncoming FROM Inventory WHERE stock = 0) AS r
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(Date) AS MaxOutgoing FROM Inventory WHERE stock = 1) AS s
```

Comment: Looks promising but I am getting an error: ...syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX(Date) AS MaxOutgoing FROM inventory WHERE stock = 1) AS r'

Comment: @mcflause - My bad. I have altered the statement. Can you verify it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, type, color, product, 
                  SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, MAX(Date) AS LatestDate, null AS stock 
            FROM inventory 
            GROUP BY id, color, type
HAVING TotalQuantity > 0

UNION ALL 

SELECT null, null, null, null, null, MAX(Date), stock 
FROM inventory WHERE stock IN (0,1) GROUP BY stock
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off running queries 2 and 3 separately from query 1. Queries 2 and 3 are of a separate concern from query 1 because you are intending to get individual values as opposed to a multi-columned list. Also, you are filtering results in query 1, but not in 2 and 3.

Sure, you can `CROSS JOIN` twice on subqueries, but then you'll be transferring that much more unnecessary data between your DB and application. You only need to retrieve two *values*, not two *entire columns* (which might I add, are unrelated to the rest of the result set — further emphasizing its inelegance).

Moreover, the `CROSS JOIN` approach ***assumes*** that there will be at least one row satisfying the condition of `SUM(Quantity) > 0`. What if none of them satisfy? ...Then you also won't have your latest in/out stock dates! Although perhaps unlikely, this use case has to be taken into consideration.

Having said that, you can rewrite your first query so as to avoid a subselect:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    color,
    type,
    product,
    SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity,
    MAX(Date) AS LatestDate
FROM 
    inventory 
GROUP BY 
    id, 
    color, 
    type
HAVING
    SUM(Quantity) > 0
```

You can combine queries 2 and 3 using conditional checks within the aggregate function `MAX()`:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN stock = 0 THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS s0_maxdate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN stock = 1 THEN Date ELSE NULL END) AS s1_maxdate
FROM
    inventory
```